# Revoke tag synonym suggestion

Tags: support, tag-synonym-process

Some time ago I suggested [gawk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gawk) as a synonym of [awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awk).

Now I notice there is no point in going ahead with the "synonymization". Since I don't see an option to revoke the request, could you kindly downvote it?

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/synonyms

Comment: Good, I got a couple of downvotes in the synonym request! Funny I got a Tumbleweed badge for this question, this is kind of complicated in Meta...

Comment: If two more people with sufficient `awk` score see this, they can downvote and it will delete itself?

Comment: Yes! It was +2, now it is 0, so just two downvotes to go :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After commenting with few people active in [awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awk) I could get the necessary downvotes for this.

So the suggested synonym is no longer available, thanks!