# How can I draw attention to a question in Meta?

Tags: support, questions, meta

There are a couple of questions I asked here in Meta that are not being resolved:

- [Removing the [less] tag from UNIX questions using the "less" command. Good thing to do?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283550/removing-the-less-tag-from-unix-questions-using-the-less-command-good-thing)
- [Revoke tag synonym suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258008/revoke-tag-synonym-suggestion)

The first one gets up/downvotes and comments from time to time, almost always being like "of course you should do X". It would be great if `X` was constant, but it tends to be either `X`, `Y` or `Z`. I even got [a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283550/removing-the-less-tag-from-unix-questions-using-the-less-command-good-thing#comment147717_283552) from a Mod, but no further info was added upon my reply.

The second one just needs some people to downvote a tag synonym I wrongly suggested, because I fear it will be approved and it would not be good.

So the thing is: how can I draw attention to questions in Meta, since we cannot start bounties in Meta? I don't like having to do what I am doing now, asking a Meta Meta question :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't... This is one of the biggest problems when using Meta in my opinion.

The best shot you have is to:

- Post in a chat room related to the subject;
- Ping a mod in chat if you both are a regular users in that chat room;
- Become a moderator :) .

Comment: You missed "* Become an SE employee", and if all else fails, "* Bribe an SE employee" (-;

Comment: @Mat: You can add that if you want ;)

Comment: I'd say, "edit to bump" is another choice, but hopefully OP can also add the update/progress, not just "bump only".

Comment: Finally, the tag synonym issue was solved by mentioning it in comments to other users. Now the suggested tag is not available any more. Regarding the other question, I will have to ping a moderator. It is a pity that this is like this, hopefully we'll find another way to approach the problem. Thanks for your answer, accepting it since it is the best we can have right now!